# How to join time series data in python with differing headings?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently have about 500 csv files worth of time series data. I am joining them using this code:

```
from glob import glob

with open('master.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
    for csv in glob('*data.csv'):
        if csv == 'master.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in open(csv, 'r'):
                singleFile.write(line)
```

However there is an issue with this, the headings of each file is not the same, as the first row has a list of companies, now as time goes on some companies retire and some companies join the market, thus there are inconsistencies as I scroll down my merged file.

To illustrate my problem I'll do an example:

This is currently the format of the first three of my csv files.

[image: current]

My desired output looks like this:

[image: desired]

Currently I am arriving at my desired output by manually moving around the columns, is there any way when merging my files python can detect a new column and move it to the right?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Data

`1.csv`:

```
a,b
1,2
1,2
```

`2.csv`:

```
b,c
2,3
2,3
```

`3.csv`:

```
c,d
3,4
3,4
```

### Pandas

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) to [load](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and convert the CSV files to dataframes. After that you can [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them to a single dataframe which can [be saved](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) back to a CSV file.

[image]

A full example:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',') for f in glob('*.csv') if not f.startswith('all.csv')], ignore_index=True, sort=False)

print(df)
#      a    b    c    d
# 0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
# 1  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0
# 3  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0
# 4  NaN  2.0  3.0  NaN
# 5  NaN  2.0  3.0  NaN

df.to_csv('all.csv', index=False)
# a,b,c,d
# 1.0,2.0,,
# 1.0,2.0,,
# ,,3.0,4.0
# ,,3.0,4.0
# ,2.0,3.0,
# ,2.0,3.0,
```

Image source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/merging.html

Comment: Okay great, however I have about 500 files, so I couldn't just type in df1,df2,df500...
Thank you for the data visualization by the way!

Comment: It's easy to load and combine multiple CSV files. Do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 2

Comment: You can use partial wildcard matching with glob and just loop through your dir and pass all the files into a list, then use pandas to concat them. If you know the data types I would declare that in the pandas.read_csv function as this will greatly speed up the process.

Comment: I added a full example. For that you just have to [install pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) with `pip install pandas`.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I also really appreciate your easily understandable example